# What are the advantages of using a view over a temporary table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

what are the advantages of using a view over temporary tables. I know that you should use a view if the data is re-used by other stored procedures but:

1. Performance-wise is it better to use a view than a temporary table?
2. If the tables that the views are based on being constantly updated is a view still better than a temporary table?
3. If I had to use a where clause against a view, am I better off using a temporary table?
4. Finally, what are the advantages/disadvantages of using a view or temporary tables?

Comment: View is shared and dynamic.  Temporary table is not shared and static.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73338615/7186739

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To discern, ask yourself if you need to reuse the information:

- a view is a glorified SELECT and it's used mainly for convenience
- you can materizalize a view, i.e. store it as a table and even index it. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986366/how-to-create-materialized-views-in-sql-server)
- use a temp table if you will not reuse the structure many times, like in a script that runs every now and then
- views will take space (especially if materialized) and having many views is difficult to maintain

Also note how temp tables are destroyed:

- if you create a temp table #tbl, it will be destroyed when it goes out of scope (e.g. at the end of the script).
- you can however create a temp table like ##tbl (with two #) and it will be destroyed when the connection ends.

Comment: "use a view if you need the data many times"
What? .. The view is just an alias for a select statement. It means that the query itself needs to be re-run every time you "query" the view. So if you need the data many times then you should use a temp table - the result is stored in memory and the data are available almost immediately.

Comment: A temp table will not be updated with the latest inserts / edits to the data source. Updating my answer

Comment: global temp tables created with two hashes ## will get destroyed when all the users referring to it close their sessions.

Answer (score 4):

1. In general, yes, as a view is just a stored select, whereas a temporary table would require some use of tempdb.
2. On this point, it makes no difference. Views are not persisted - they return the data from their base tables.
3. doesn't make s difference either.
4. Views are persisted (that is, the text of the select statement is persisted) - they give you a layer over the database which allows you to change the database without effecting the clients using the view.

Comment: Thanks! That really cleared things up for me. In general, since there is no difference in performance, should you only use a view when the same data is being constantly queried?

Comment: So, views are persisted or not?, the points 2 and 4 seem to contradict themselves

Comment: @Lamak - The view, a _select statement_ is persisted. The values returned are persisted in the base tables, not the view itself.

Comment: @RT88 - Well. It depends on what you are trying to do. Temp tables just add overheads both to tempdb and in the need to code for them.

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing ideas

views are encapsulated logic, nothing more, it helps with code reuse
temporary tables are real, physical storage where you hold data

you cant compare those two, as both have different applications

i dont like using views in general :)

Comment: It's confusing?? I haven't in the past used view's much in my stored procedures and have used temporary tables alot. From reading various articles on this subject though it seems that using temporary tables is a bad idea? I just wanted to be clear on when / which situations would it make sense to use a view or a temporary table?

Comment: You can materialize views so views are not just definitions